# NSData from base64 encoded binary string?

Tags: objective-c

I have a file that I am reading as binary, and encoding it with base64, and sending it via an api.

The file looks like this:

```
f = File.open 'brass.syx'
 => #<File:brass.syx>
2.2.0 :022 > f.binmode
 => #<File:brass.syx>
2.2.0 :023 > f.read
 => "\xF0C\x00\t \x00*8\x14Fc\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00?\x04O\x0E\x1507\x162b=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x04F\x06\x06B\\\x1625=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x04O\x02\x00.#\x168cVV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009\fO\x02\x00%\"\x0F@U\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\bC\x02\x009\x18\x13<cVV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\bc\x02\x00^C_<5222\x11\x0F#\x00\x05\x00\x10\x18BRASS 1   M8\x14Fc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x00O\x0E\x1507\x162b=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x00F\x06\x06B\\\x1625=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00O\x02\x00.#\x162cVV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009\x04M\x02\x00%\"\x0FFU\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x04F\x02\x007\x18\x137cVV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\bc\x02\x00^C_<2222\x11\x0E#\x00\x05\x000\x18BRASS 2   5 \x1C:ca`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05d\bP\x00\x00C$\eGcac\x00'\x00\x00\x0F@\x00c\x00\x00C$\eGcac\x00'\x00\x00\x0FH\x00c\x00\x00C$\eGcac\x00'\x00\x00\x0F0\x00c\x00\x00# \x1C:ca`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x00X\x00\x00C$\eGcac\x00'\x00\x00\x0F8\x00c\x00\x00T__<2222\x15\x0F%\x00\x00\x00\b\x18BRASS 3   M\e\x101Zc[\x00\x00\x00\f\x00p\x000\x06\x00F\e\x101Zc[\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00P\x00[\x00\x00F\e\x101Zc[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\b\x00L\x00\x00@(\x17*ca^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00H\x00c\x00\x002\x1A\x12\x1F^c_\x00(\x00\x05\x00h\x00X\x00\x00Acc)ccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00c\x00\x00cccc2222\x01\r!\x00\n\x00\x11\x18BRASS 4   F\e\x101Zc[\x00\x00\x00\f\x00\b\x00c\x02\x00F\e\x101Zc[\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\b\x00A\x00\x00F\e\x101Zc[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00h\x00F\x00\x00@(\x17*ca^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00c\x00\x002\x1A\t*^c]\x00(\x00\x05\x00p\x00S\x00\x00Acc)ccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00c\x00\x00cccc2222\b\x0E\x0E\x00\r\x00\x11\x18BRASS ENS F\r<5bPU\x006\x00\x00\x00I\x00\\\x0225\r<5bPU\x006\x00\x00\x009\x009\x0225\r<5bPU\x006\x00\x00\x00)\x04T\x022>F\x146c\\T\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Z\x00b\x0225.<5b__\x006\x00\x00\x00\x01\x04R\x02\x00>F\x146ca_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x04c\x02\x00^C_<2222\x01\x0F&!\x00G\x10\fBRASS 5THSH\e\x101Zc[\x00\x00\x00\f\x00p\x00c\x06\x00F\e\x101Zc[\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00P\x00I\x00\x00F\e\x101Zc[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00U\x00\x00@(\x17*ca^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00H\x00c\x00\x002\x1A\x12\x1F^c_\x00(\x00\x05\x00P\x00Y\x00\x00Acc)ccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x00\x00cccc2222\e\x0F!\x00\n\x00\x01\x18PERCBRASS F$\x1A3c`^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x049\x03Q\x02\x009B\x113c^Z\x00'\x00\x00\x06;\x03c\x02\x009B\x113c^Z\x00'\x00\x00\x06;\x03c\x02\x008\x11\x113c^Z\x00'\x00\x00\x06;\x03c\x02\x00F%\x038c6\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x06:\aY\x00\b<B0:c6\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x06:\ac\x00\x00T__<2222\x15\r\x1E\x00\x00\x00\x18\fBRASS BC1 2=\x130cbc\x00'\x00\x0E\x00\t\x03P\x02\x012\x14\x142c__\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x03c\x02\x002\x14\x141c__\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x03a\x02\x002\x14\x141c`_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x03c\x02\x002\x0F\x0F1ccc\x00.\x00=\x00r\x007\x00@2\x14\x141c__\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x03c\x02\x00^C_<2222\x15\x0F\"!\x00\x00\x18\x18BRASS BC2 M\x1E\x104ca`\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x1A\x06R\x02\x012\e\x104cac\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00R\x03c\x01\x0F2\e\x104cac\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x03a\x01\x0F2\e\x104cac\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\"\x03c\x01\x0F6\x1C&1cba\x00.\x00c\x00r\t^\x02\x0081-3c`c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x03c\x01\x00^C_<2222\x15\x0F\"!\x00\x00\x18\fBC BRSENSM5 \x182ca^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x1CM\x02\x005 \x182ca^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x10O\x02\x005\x1E\x162ca^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\f@\x02\x00.#\x162c`_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00K\x18O\x02\x00%\"\x0FFU\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Z\f`\x02\x00=\x17\x117cVV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00*\x04c\x02\x00^C_<1322\x11\x0F#\x00\x00\x00\x00\fHORNS 1   M8\x14Fc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x00O\x0E\x1507\x162b=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x00F\x06\x06B\\\x1625=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00R\x02\x00.#\x162c`_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00;\x10P\x02\x00%\"\x0FFU\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x04F\x02\x00=\x17\x117cVV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\bc\x02\x00^C_<2222\x11\x0F#\x00\x00\x000\fHORNS 2   M8\x14Fc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x00T\x0E\x1507\x162b=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x00F\x06\x06B\\\x1625A>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00]\x02\x00.#\x118cV[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00r\fP\x02\x00-\"2@ca_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00r\bS\x02\x009\x18\x13<cV\\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x00c\x02\x00^C_<5222\x11\x0F#\x00\x00\x00\x10\fHORNS 3   M \x182ca^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x1CM\x02\x005 \x182ca^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x10O\x02\x005\x1E\x162ca^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\f@\x02\x00.#\x162c`_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00K\x18O\x02\x00%\"\x0FFU\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Z\f`\x02\x00=\x17\x117cVV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00*\x04c\x02\x00^C_<1322\x11\x0F#\x00\x00\x00\x00\fHORNS 4   #\x19\x1CDccc\x00'62\x05t\x1AT\x02\x002\x13\x1FGc`c\x00'\x00\x00\x0F(\x04c\x02\x002\x13\x1FGc`c\x00'\x00\x00\x0FH\x04c\x02\x002\x13\x1FGc`c\x00'\x00\x00\x0FH\x04c\x02\x004\x1A\x1D/c``\x00\e\x00\x04\x03H\x01^\x02\x009\x18\x122c^`\x00'\x00\x00\x0FB\x04c\x02\x00T__<2222\x15\x0F 8\x00\x00\b\fHORNS 5   ;\x19\x1CDc^^\x00'62\x05t\rO\x02\x004$)Gcbb\x00'\x00\x00\x0F(\bc\x02\x007$)Gcbb\x00'\x00\x00\x0FH\bc\x02\x009LRGcbb\x00'\x00\x00\x0FH\bc\x02\x004\x1A\x1D/]ba\x00\e\x00\x04\x03H\x00S\x02\x009\x18\x122c^`\x00'\x00\x00\x0FB\x00c\x02\x00T__<2222\x15\x0F 8\x00\x00\b\fHORNS 6   c\e\x101Zc[\x00\x00\x00\f\x00p\f^\x00\x00.\e\x105Zc[\x00\x00\x00\x04\x008\x00T\x00\x00.\e\x101Zc[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00K\x00\x00E(\x17,ca^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00c\x01#1\x1A\x12*^c\x00\x00(\x00\x05\x00P\bU\x00\x00Bcc,ccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00c\x01!cccc2222\b\x0E#\x00\x00\x00\x01\x18HORNS 7   F8\x14Fc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x04T\x0E\x1507\x162b=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x04F\x06\x06B\\\x1625A>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x04]\x02\x004\x1C28cVX\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00r\rW\x02\x004\x1C28cVZ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00r\x05`\x02\x009\x18\x13<cV\\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x04c\x02\x00^C_<5222\x11\x0F#\x00\x00\x00\x00\fHORNS BC1 58\x14Fc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x00O\x0E\x0007\x162b=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x00F\x06\"B\\\x1625=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x03R\x02\x00.#\x162c`_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00;\x03O\x02\x00%\"\x0FFca_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x03Q\x02\x00=\x1C,7c\\c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x03c\x02\x00^C_<1322\x11\x0F#\x00\x00\x00\x10\x18HORNS BC2 ,8\x14Fc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x04O\x0E\x1507\x162b=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x04F\x06\x06B\\\x1625=>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x04O\x02\x00.#\x168cVV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009\fO\x02\x00%\"\x0F@U\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\bC\x02\x009\x18\x13<cVV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\bc\x02\x00^C_<5222\x11\x0F#\x00\x03\x00\x10\fFRENCHHORN.8\x14Fc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\fc\x0E\x150\f\x162c==\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005\x002\f\x04BL\x162c==\x00?\x00\x00\x00=\x10J\x02\x00)\f\x162c==\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00=\x04O\x02\x00c\f\x162U\x00\x00\x00D\x00`\x04:\x1C2\x04\x05F\x18\x137cVV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x10c\x02\x00VC_<4222\x11\x0F\"-\x05\x00 \x18TRUMPET   M\e\x10\x1FZc^\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\b\x00c\x04\x00F\e\x10(Zc_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00A\x00\x00F\e\x10'Zc^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\b\x00R\x00\x00@(\x17*ca^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x00\x002\x1A\t$^c^\x00\x18\x00\x05\x00p\x04V\x00\x00Acc)ccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00h\x00c\x00\x00cccc2222\b\x0E\x17\x00\v\x00!\x18ANLGBRASS cL\n c\\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00R\x04\x00LI\n7c\\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00P\x04\x008J\n-bb$\x00b\x00\x00\x008\x00H\x04\x006\x0F\n/c\\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00h\x00`\x04\x005. =c]Z\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\b\x00S\x02\x00P8\n-bb$\x00b\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x02\x00T__<2222\x01\x0F\x1E?\x06\x008\fORCHESTRA ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x02\x00cccc2222\x00\b#\x00\x00\x001\x18          ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x02\x00cccc2222\x00\b#\x00\x00\x001\x18          ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x02\x00cccc2222\x00\b#\x00\x00\x001\x18          ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x02\x00cccc2222\x00\b#\x00\x00\x001\x18          ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x02\x00cccc2222\x00\b#\x00\x00\x001\x18          ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x02\x00cccc2222\x00\b#\x00\x00\x001\x18          ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x02\x00cccc2222\x00\b#\x00\x00\x001\x18          ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x02\x00cccc2222\x00\b#\x00\x00\x001\x18          ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x02\x00ccccccc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00c\x02\x00cccc2222\x00\b#\x00\x00\x001\x18          q\xF7"
 2.2.0 :024 > Base64.encode64 _ # <-- what is sent over the wire
  => "8EMACSAAKjgURmMAAABjAAAAPwRPDhUwNxYyYj0+AAAAAAAwBEYGBkJcFjI1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\nICAgICAgIHH3\n"
```

When my the api call is resolved, I have tried both:

```
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:application/octet-stream;base64,%@", encodedString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
```

and

```
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:encodedString options:0];
```

Both result in data being nil...  How can I properly get an NSData object from my base64 encoded string of binary data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide the `NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters` option to `initWithBase64EncodedString`, it will ignore the newline characters that occur in your string.

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:encodedString options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
```

When I did that, your base64 string was decoded properly.